# Por qué no me ejecuta la función y me deja seguir el código?

Tags: java, jframe, class

Para este caso creo que solo es necesario explicar que tengo en un Jframe una función que cambia de valores a ciertos JTextFields ahí mismo. Para que esta se ejecute la llamo en otro Jframe de esta manera:

Esta es la función en el Jframe 1:

```
public void cambiarvalores(){

    Integer cv1, cv2, cv3, cv4, cv5;
    cv1=ep1-llevap1;
    cv2=ep2-llevap2;
    cv3=ep3-llevap3;
    cv4=ep4-llevap4;
    cv5=ep5-llevap5;

    e1.setText(cv1.toString());
    e2.setText(cv2.toString());
    e3.setText(cv3.toString());
    e4.setText(cv4.toString());
    e5.setText(cv5.toString());


}
```

Esta es la llamada para que me cambie los valores desde el otro jframe (Jframe 2) y luego me abra el Jframe 1:

```
private void btnsiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      
    ventana.cambiarvalores();
    ventana open=new ventana();
    open.setVisible(true);
    open.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    dispose();
}
```

Cuando ejecuto y presiono el btnsi me sale esto y no me deja continuar:

> 

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at inventario.ventana.cambiarvalores(ventana.java:771)  at    inventario.mas.btnsiActionPerformed(mas.java:66)  at    inventario.mas.access$000(mas.java:3)     at    inventario.mas$1.actionPerformed(mas.java:23)     at    javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at    javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at    javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at    javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at    javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)    at    javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)    at    java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)  at    java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)  at    java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)     at    java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)     at    java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at    java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at    java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)    at    java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at    java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)     at    java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)    at    java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)    at    java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at    java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)    at    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at    java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at    java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)   at    java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)    at    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at    java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)   at    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at    java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

A penas estoy iniciando en Java, agradezco su comprensión.

Comment: Pon el código completo, no se ve cómo creas algunos objetos ni como se llaman. Tampoco se ve el contexto.

Comment: Es que son demasiadas lineas, pero lo puse en este Paste Bin: https://pastebin.com/dgkLAfnr

Comment: En todo el código no veo que aparezca el método `btnsiActionPerformed` por tanto no se puede ver cómo o desde dónde se está llamando a ese método ¿?

Comment: Mira, perdón. Lo pongo en otro paste bin para que sea un poquito más ordenado: https://pastebin.com/fedcuCmg

Comment: Trato de encontrar la lógica que estás siguiendo pero no doy con ella. ¿A qué contenedor agregas los botones? Yo veo que creas una ventana por un lado, pero no le agregas nada. Luego veo que haces una llamada a `cambiarvalores()` que tampoco aparece en el código. No entiendo realmente la lógica de tu programa. ¿El `btnsi` se muestra en pantalla y el error salta cuando lo presionas?

Comment: Mira, son dos ventanas. la primera ejecuta todo. Hay otra que no publiqué que no tiene nada que nos interese. Y esa que no publiqué llama al Jframe mas. Cuando ejecuto todo y le presiono al sí sale el error. Solo quiero restar los valores que tengo en los spinners a los e1...e5 pero necesito que termine el proceso, si lo hago antes de que salgan el resto de pantallas puede que se cancele entonces me resta y no hubo interacción. No sé si me haga entender. Es que es un poquito confusp D:

Comment: Si es confuso para ti, imagínate para alguien que no conoce la lógica de tu programa ni lo que hace. Los errores de *`Null Pointer Exception`*  ocurren porque hay algo nulo en tu programa. Encontrar eso para alguien que no tiene nada que ver con el código es como buscar una aguja en un pajar. Revisa la lógica de tu código paso por paso, cómo se crean los elementos, como se añaden, como interactúan, y encontrarás el problema. A veces son errores infantiles como declarar un objeto con otro nombre, olvidar inicializarlo, o crearlo  dos veces o cosas así.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el problema es la conversion de Integer con el toString Prueba así

```
public void cambiarvalores(){

    Integer cv1, cv2, cv3, cv4, cv5;
    cv1=ep1-llevap1;
    cv2=ep2-llevap2;
    cv3=ep3-llevap3;
    cv4=ep4-llevap4;
    cv5=ep5-llevap5;

    e1.setText(String.valueOf(cv1));
    e2.setText(String.valueOf(cv2));
    e3.setText(String.valueOf(cv3));
    e4.setText(String.valueOf(cv4));
    e5.setText(String.valueOf(cv5));


}
```

Comment: No, acabo de intentarlo y salió el mismo error, amigo D:

Comment: He logrado tantas cosas con esta aplicación y lo único que me falta para presentarlo en la U es lograr hacer esa resta y no he podido. No sé qué es lo que sucede :(